# Mysql select within a foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

How can I get MySQL select in foreach?

My code is :

```
$start = new DateTime($giris);
$end = new DateTime($cikis);
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    $datex = $dt->format("Y-m-d"). PHP_EOL;
    $sorgu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM takvimler WHERE `date`='$datex'"); 
    $veri = mysql_fetch_assoc($sorgu);
    $don = $veri['price'];
    echo $don;
}
```

**Note**: I want `echo $don;`

Comment: Fix: Remove `. PHP_EOL` it is not part of the date! But, what is else going wrong?

Comment: @MehmetGenç If that didn't resolve the issue you should state that here (and what now happens). I think most people that view this thread are going to view it as solved..

Answer (score -1):

```
$start = new DateTime($giris);
$end = new DateTime($cikis);
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $dt) {
$datex = $dt->format("Y-m-d"). PHP_EOL;
$sorgu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM takvimler WHERE `date`='$datex'"); 
$veri = mysql_fetch_assoc($sorgu);
$don .= $veri['price'];

}
echo $don;
```

Comment: What are you proposing here? Answers should have an explanation.

Comment: $don .= $veri['price']; using "." dot operator i concatinate the array value and echo it outside the loop.

Comment: Why are you suggesting that? Whats the difference with OPs code? OP has `echo $don;` in the loop so it should be outputting already.. Also that'll throw a notice as is.